# Reward correct downvotes by awarding reputation to downvoters if question was closed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting, down-votes

By awarding reputation points to downvoters on closed. It will create feedback loop with award for correct downvoting.

Comment: What's the point of this? If you really don't think enough questions are getting closed, then why not just give people points for *closing* them?

Comment: Downvotes and close votes are not at all the same thing, they just often come together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea. Because downvotes on questions are now free, this would generate not only reputation out of the nothing, this would also trigger a *unnecessary wave* of downvotes on everything what might be closed some day. Additionally people could start gaming the system by throwing in there 3k privilege to close questions.

Example:

- 3k-Guy sees not so good question
- Downvote
- Vote to close
- Repeat four times with different users
- Free reputation